# Convert bootstrap datepicker to datetime.datetime format

Tags: python, bootstrap-4

Am using bootstrap datepicker for my django application and I need the format to be as Python's `datetime.datetime` format:
For example: `2022-02-15 19:21:38.604 +0530`

But as of now the plugin has only D,M,Y etc. Any idea how to create a custom format which is similar to Python's `datetime`?

Comment: You can use [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to create a `datatime` instance from a **string**. Can you convert a bootstrap datepicker into a string? You can also create one by calling its constructor and passing it the data needed — see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime).

Comment: Ya but i wish to do this on frontend instead of backend !